# Titling tabs in Terminal

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal

I'd like to be able to set the titles on my tabs to short, easy-to-remember things, since I often have a few open. You can use Command-I and set the Title that way, but OSX appends the name of the currently running process to that title, (e.g. "test title -- bash").

Is there any way to set the full text of the tab title?

This is on OSX 10.6. There used to be a way to do this on 10.5 using SIMBL, but that no longer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Preferences choose the windows tab for your set of settings. There is an option Active process name - if this is not ticked then you should not see the command in the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

I turned off, 'show active process' in preferences.  Along with all the other trivia.  I want *different* trivia.

As an example, I have the following two lines in my `.bash_profile` in my home directory. (`.bash_profile` gets executed in every new tab/window)

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n -e "\033]0;`basename $PWD`\007"'
function vi { echo -n -e "\033]0;vi $1\007" ; vim $1 ;}
```

The first command sets the tab to the last directory in my current bath.
e.g. if I'm in `~sherwood/foo/bar` this will be bar

The second one in effect turns vi (my editor of choice) into a pair of commands that does the same sort of echo, but now it sets the tab to show that I'm editing this file.  So if I'm editing `~sherwood/foo/bar/baz`, it will show `vi baz`

Note that it will show whatever you told vi.  So if you type 
`vi /some/long/path/to/a/../../name`  that's what the tab will show, or at least as much of it as will fit.

At this time I have not found a way to set the title bar differently from the tab.

Comment: Oh, I am not very good at bash. Can you, please, tell how to title current tab with current directory where I stay?

Answer (score 1):

You could install [xtermcontrol](http://www.thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/) (also via fink, macports, etc.), and then use that to set the title to whatever you want. I have the following `cd` in my `.bash_profile`, so that any time I change directories the directory is in the xterm window title:

```
cd() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    builtin cd "$@"; xtermcontrol --title "$@"
  else
    builtin cd ~;  xtermcontrol --title "~"
  fi
}
```

You can also set up aliases or customize your ssh settings so that hostnames are added to the title when you leave this host, etc.